# JavaFX Unable to set data when enums used with custom cell factory

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

[Full Source Code Attached]

I have a javafx TableView with 3 columns ("Name", "Gender", "Country"). I'm attaching cell factories to all my columns like below.

```
nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
genderCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(GenderEnum.values()));
countryCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("India", "USA"));
```

I didn't implement any commit logic on my own. Now i change the value in all the 3 columns and then print the data. I'm able to see the changed value on all columns except the genderCol. The only difference about that column is it is using an enum.

When I change the value in the countryCol(that also ComoboBoxTableCell) the countryProperty is called twice first with old value then with new value but for genderCol, genderProperty is called only once.

You can copy and execute the code, print the data first without changing anything and then change the values on all 3 columns then print the data. Check now except the genderCol other columns have the changed value.

Am I missing anything or doing anything wrong with the enum

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            final VBox root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
            final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>

<VBox spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Name" fx:id="nameCol">
          <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="name" /></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Gender" fx:id="genderCol">
          <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="gender" /></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Country" fx:id="countryCol">
          <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="country" /></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button text="Print Data"  onAction="#printData"/>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

MainController.java

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import application.Person.GenderEnum;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

/**
 * @author Saravana Kumar M
 *
 */
public class MainController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person, GenderEnum> genderCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person, String> countryCol;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final URL location, final ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        this.nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        this.genderCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(GenderEnum.values()));
        this.countryCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("India", "USA"));

        final Person p1 = new Person("A", "M", "India");
        final Person p2 = new Person("B", "F", "USA");
        final Person p3 = new Person("C", "N", "India");
        final Person p4 = new Person("D", null, "USA");
        final Person p5 = new Person("E", "M", "India");
        final Person p6 = new Person("F", "F", "USA");
        final Person p7 = new Person("G", "N", "India");
        final Person p8 = new Person("H", null, "USA");

        this.table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8));

        this.genderCol.setOnEditCommit((event) -> this.doThis(event));
    }

    private void doThis(final CellEditEvent<Person, GenderEnum> event)
    {
        System.out.println(event);
        System.out.println(event.getOldValue());
        System.out.println(event.getNewValue());
        System.out.println(event.getRowValue());
    }

    @FXML
    public void printData()
    {
        this.table.getItems().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * @author Saravana Kumar M
 *
 */
public class Person
{
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final ObjectProperty<GenderEnum> gender;
    private final StringProperty country;

    public Person(final String name, final String gender, final String country)
    {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);

        if(gender == null)
        {
            this.gender = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        else
        {
            this.gender = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(GenderEnum.valueOf(gender));
        }

        this.country = new SimpleStringProperty(country);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public GenderEnum getGender()
    {
        return this.gender.get();
    }

    public void setGender(final GenderEnum gender)
    {
        this.gender.set(gender);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<GenderEnum> genderProperty()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return this.country.get();
    }

    public void setCountry(final String country)
    {
        this.country.set(country);
    }

    public StringProperty countryProperty()
    {
        return this.country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "name : " + this.name + " name.get : " + this.name.get() + " gender : " + this.gender + " gender.get : " + this.gender.get() + " country : " + this.country.get() + " country.get : " + this.country.get();
    }

    public enum GenderEnum
    {
        M("Male"), F("Female"), N("None");

        private final String label;
        private GenderEnum(final String label)
        {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return this.label;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`TableView` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html):

> By default the TableColumn edit commit handler is non-null, with a
>   default handler that attempts to overwrite the property value for the
>   item in the currently-being-edited row. It is able to do this as the
>   `Cell.commitEdit(Object)` method is passed in the new value, and this is
>   passed along to the edit commit handler via the `CellEditEvent` that is
>   fired. It is simply a matter of calling
>   `TableColumn.CellEditEvent.getNewValue()` to retrieve this value.
>
> It is very important to note that if you call
>   `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler)` with your own
>   `EventHandler`, then you will be removing the default handler. Unless
>   you then handle the writeback to the property (or the relevant data
>   source), nothing will happen. You can work around this by using the
>   [`TableColumnBase.addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType, javafx.event.EventHandler)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setOnEditCommit-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method to add a
>   `TableColumn.EDIT_COMMIT_EVENT` EventType with your desired EventHandler
>   as the second argument. Using this method, you will not replace the
>   default implementation, but you will be notified when an edit commit
>   has occurred.

Since you have

```
    this.genderCol.setOnEditCommit((event) -> this.doThis(event));
```

in your controller class, you remove the default handler that updates the property. If you replace this with

```
    this.genderCol.addEventHandler(TableColumn.<Person, GenderEnum>editCommitEvent(),
        event -> this.doThis(event));
```

it will work as expected. (Note the documentation is incorrect in telling you how to get the event type. Also note your handler will be invoked before the default one, so the output from `getRowValue()` will show the values *before* updating, but pressing the button to display the values will give the new ones.)

Comment: Awesome. ThankQ So much. Sorry for asking another question but i feel it is related. If i want a TableColumn with a combobox as cell factory, then when should i choose built-in ComboBoxTableCell and when should i go for my own implementation?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Ah, hard to answer that question other than the obvious: use the built-in one if it does what you want and use your own implementation if it doesn't. I usually prefer to have the combo box permanently displayed and update the model "live", as in the implementation of `CheckBoxTableCell`, so I use my own implementation for that.

Comment: Great. Thanks Again.